# Cp: target is not a directory

Tags: bash, heroku, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a bash script with this line:

```
cp -R /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/$GCC_VERSION/* /app/.apt/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/$GCC_VERSION
```

Full script: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/blob/cedar-14/bin/compile

Unfortunately it fails with `cp: target ‘/app/.apt/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8’ is not a directory`

Any tips what could be wrong? Unfortunately I do not have much experience with bash.

Previously this script was running alone and it was working. Now I had to add some `apt-get install` before it, and it started to fail so I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Is the target a directory ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no directory with the name 4.8...Thats your problem :)

Run this before your cp command:

```
mkdir -p /app/.apt/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/$GCC_VERSION
```

It creates all directories in the given path!

Comment: Have to note that `mkdir` command should be on the same line with `cp` command in order to make this work

Comment: Is there a way to do this recursively for many folders?

Answer (score 7):

This should work, add `/` at the end of `cp` command to make it clear for it that its dir:

```
mkdir -p /app/.apt
cp -R $BUILD_DIR/.apt/* /app/.apt/
```